# Tighter upper bound of $\operatorname{tr}[ (\mathcal{H}[L]\rho )^2] \leq \delta$

Tags: quantum-state, mathematics

I am wondering about an upper bound of the trace function $\operatorname{tr}[ (\mathcal{H}[L]\rho )^2] \leq \delta$ (we assume that $\rho$ is the $N\times N$ density matrix representing the quantum state, $L$ is the $N\times N$ Hermitian operator $L=L^\dagger$, and $\mathcal{H}[L]\rho=L\rho+\rho L-2 \operatorname{tr}(L\rho)\rho$ ).
I would like to have some advice from you.

Comment: What do you want from the upper bound? You could apply Cauchy-Schwarz or Hölder inequalities but without more context I don't know why they'd be more useful to you than the original expression.

Comment: I want to make the upper bound $\delta$ does not depend on $\rho$ and tighter.